# How can avoid hardcoded "C:\Program Files" in batch code

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a batch file.I have differentiate "C:\Program Files" and "C:\Program Files(86)" based on windows bit.
But i don't want to hardcode the "C:\Program Files". How can i achieve that.

Comment: Are you talking about `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` environment variables? type `set Program` in a new command prompt window and check them out...

Comment: %ProgramFiles% working for me.Thats what i need.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hard-code the path you else want to write it, maybe with a prompt asking you to write the full path:

```
set /P Path="Insert your path here: "
```

This will prompt *Insert [...]:  _* so you can write in your path, without hardcoding it.

Hope this help.

Comment: %ProgramFiles% working for me.Thats what i need.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that with a batch file :

```
@echo off
set "strProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles%"
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" set "strProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
echo %strProgramFiles%
pause
```